# Difference between Media and Node object? (Umbraco)

Tags: c#, webforms, umbraco

In Umbraco, what is the difference between a Media object versus a Node object?

(I'm working on a WebForms project.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With regards to your project being webforms, the use of these classes makes no difference. Actually, you probably shouldn't even be using these two classes at all, as I describe below.

In v4.7, the `umbraco.NodeFactory.Node` class is the default method for retrieving published content from Umbraco. The published content, as Martijn points out is the XML cache. This superseded the `umbraco.presentation.nodeFactory.Node` class which is now marked as obsolete and so should never be used even in a v4.7 project.

In the latest versions of Umbraco, `DynamicNode` and then `IPublishedContent` were introduced to replace the reliance of using `Node` in the published UI.

Likewise in v4.7, `Media` is the class used for retrieving any object from Umbraco media library. Again as Martijn points out this requires a call to the database. Media is also now marked as obsolete and should not be used.

However, since v4.8 `Media` was replaced with `DynamicMedia`. This does not call the database but instead calls Umbraco's Lucene index that holds all the information about the media items in the media library, and so is significantly faster. In the latest versions, the preferred method of retrieving media is actually to use `IPublishedContent` see here http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Templating/Mvc/querying

In the latest versions of Umbraco there is a new `Umbraco.Core.Models.Media` class, which as it happens *does* make calls to the database however this class is part of the new Umbraco API and so should not be used in the published UI.

Comment: nicely added extra explanation to my answer :) +1

Answer (score 2):

The media object is for media items. The Node object is for content tems.
Check out these links.
[http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/management/media](http://our.umbraco.org/Documentation/Reference/Management-v6/Models/Media)
http://our.umbraco.org/Documentation/Reference/Querying/uQuery/Content/Nodes

Also a Node is read from the XML cache and Media is read directly from the database.